# CATransformation3D Transformed Label not saving on image

Tags: swift, catransform3d, catransform3drotate

I am currently working on an Image app where I can put a Text Sticker that made with a UIView. I Applied CATransform3D to change the Perspective of the UIView. When I change the Values, it works properly and changes the Perspective View of the UIView. But when I try to Save the Image It goes to it's default position.

Here is the Code 
Transformation

```
func transformation ()
{
    var transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = 1.0 / -200
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(sliderX.value), 0, 1, 0)
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, CGFloat(sliderY.value), 1, 0, 0)
    textStickerView.currentlyEditingLabel.layer.transform = transform
}
```

Saving Function

```
var imgSize = CGSize(width: mainImageView.bounds.size.width, height: mainImageView.bounds.size.height)

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    mainImageView.addSubview(textStickerView)
    mainImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let rowImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true) instead of mainImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)

```
extension UIView {
func asImage() -> UIImage {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
            format.opaque = isOpaque
            format.scale = 1.0
            let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds, format: format)
            return renderer.image { rendererContext in
                //layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext) // can not save transform3D
                drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            }
        } else {
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, true, 1.0)
            //self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!) // can not save transform3D
            drawHierarchy(in: frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return image ?? UIImage()
        }
    }
}
```